# How can I use the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet package to create a branch in TFS source control?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I'm using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet package for some custom scripting. I'd like to create branches in my TFS source control in VSTS, but I can't seem to find any functionality in this package to create any kind of branch, whether in TFVC or Git. Am I missing something or is the package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet). For TFVC, you need to use "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client". Following is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplica
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL = "https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(URL));
            VersionControlServer vcs = ttpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            string sourcepath = "$/ProjectNmae/SourceBranch";
            string targetpath = "$/ProjectNmae/TargetBranch";
            vcs.CreateBranch(sourcepath,targetpath,VersionSpec.Latest);
        }
    }
}
```

Update: For "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client", it access to VSTS via Rest API. However, the Rest API for TFVC and Git can only get the branches for now, it cannot create branch. So you cannot see the method in "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" either.

> Integrate with Team Foundation Server 2015 and Visual Studio Team
>   Services from desktop-based, ASP.NET, and other Windows applications.
>   Provides access to version control, work item tracking, build, and
>   more via public REST APIs.

Comment: This code is actually for legacy TFS. I'm using the newer packages for vsts, and the code here does not exist in those packages

Comment: @AlexMarshall Sorry for didn't check your question carefully. I have updated my answer.

Comment: any idea when this feature is going to be added? My team uses powershell to script most of our scrum process to reduce overhead and we need the ability to programmatically create branches

Comment: @AlexMarshall You can submit a feature request for this on VSTS User Voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services. And for now, I recommend you to use legacy TFS API in powershell script as an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

For a VSTS GIT repo you can create a branch using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.GitHttpClient` and a 2 of the Refs methods.

If you inspect the XHR requests in your browser devtools on VSTS visualstudio.com while you create a branch you can see how they do it.

- First they get the lastest commit id from the source branch
- Then they send a refs modify

First find the source branch you want to base your new from using the `GetRefsAsync`.https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#just-branches

My example I want to branch from **master**.

(*this example was written in a console app, so ignore the GetAwaiter().GetResult() if your code is in an async method*)

```
var client = new GitHttpClient(uri, creds);
var masterRefs = client.GetRefsAsync(repo.Id, filter: "heads/master").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var masterRef = masterRefs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "refs/heads/master");
```

This will give you the latest commit id to base the branch from.

Then send a refs modify using the ObjectId from the masterRef as the New Objectid
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/refs#modify-one-or-more-refs

```
GitRefUpdate newRef = new GitRefUpdate
{
    Name = "refs/heads/your-new-branch",
    NewObjectId = masterRef.ObjectId,
    OldObjectId = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
};
// create branch
var updateResult = client.UpdateRefsAsync(new[] { newRef }, repo.Id).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```